# Using Attribute as a color in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I want to implement various design themes in my application. I've looked at a lot of tutorials and a lot of questions on this place, but I can't get it to work.

I have this:

attrs.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   
    <attr name="EditText" format="reference"/>
   
</resources>
```

colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>

    <!-- DARK THEME COLORS -->

    <color name="Dark_EditText">#FFFFFF</color>

    <!-- LIGHT THEME COLORS -->

    <color name="Light_EditText">#000000</color>
  

</resources>
```

styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <!-- <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"> -->

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="LightTheme" parent="AppTheme">

        <item name="EditText">@color/Light_EditText</item>

    </style>

    <style name="DarkTheme" parent="AppTheme">
   
        <item name="EditText">@color/Dark_EditText</item>
   
    </style>
    
    </resources>
```

When i use this attrs in a layout, i do this:

```
<EditText
    ...
     android:textColor="?attr/EditText"
    ...
 />
```

It gives me the following error when compiling:

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #133 in com.osw.oswlistas:layout/aprender03c_layout: Binary XML file line #133 in com.osw.oswlistas:layout/aprender03c_layout: Error inflating class EditText
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #133 in com.oswort.oswlistas:layout/aprender03c_layout: Error inflating class EditText

The line #133 is the android:textColor="?attr/EditText"

I know I'm doing something wrong, but I can't find it. Can you help me?

Comment: replace `?attr/editTextColor` with `?attr/EditText`

Comment: @SwapnilPadaya maybe that's worth writing and explaining as an answer